# How to address Inkscape with Win32Com?

Tags: python, win32com, inkscape

I've used win32com successfully to interact with MS Visio. Great library. Now I would like to do the same with Inkscape but can't seem to find any adequate information in the net.

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants
app = win32com.client.Dispatch(Inkscape.Application
app.Visible = 1
```

returns

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in _GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx)
     88                 try:
---> 89                         IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
     90                 except pythoncom.ole_error:

com_error: (-2147221005, 'Ungültige Klassenzeichenfolge', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ce241241c43e> in <module>
----> 1 getVisio()

<ipython-input-3-266ab8177f92> in getVisio()
      2     ''' gets a handle on the visio application.
      3     sets global vApp'''
----> 4     vApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Inkscape.Application")
      5     vApp.Visible =1
      6     return vApp

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py in Dispatch(dispatch, userName, resultCLSID, typeinfo, UnicodeToString, clsctx)
     93   """
     94   assert UnicodeToString is None, "this is deprecated and will go away"
---> 95   dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
     96   return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, userName, resultCLSID, typeinfo, clsctx=clsctx)
     97 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(IDispatch, userName, clsctx)
    112         else:
    113                 userName = str(userName)
--> 114         return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
    115 
    116 def _GetDescInvokeType(entry, invoke_type):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in _GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx)
     89                         IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
     90                 except pythoncom.ole_error:
---> 91                         IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
     92         else:
     93                 # may already be a wrapped class.

com_error: (-2147221005, 'Ungültige Klassenzeichenfolge', None, None)
```

​I don't understand what the error message is telling me.
Any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all applications support COM interfacing. Can you run VBA with Inkscape? If just needing to launch app, Python can do so with its standard library to run any external .exe executable.

Comment: Thank you parfait, but I'm looking for a full control of the application, nut just launching it. How can I know I Inkscape supports COM interfacing?

Comment: Read docs or manuals/specs of application. Alternatively, check the list under Tools \ References in VBA editor for any Office product or check registries. Usually with installation of the application, any COM libraries are installed.